# Create writable combobox with vba

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I want to create a combobox on the cell the user click, and permit the user to write and/or choose (an autocompletion similar to google), set it to the cell and close combobox.

I have this code which create the box :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lst
If Not Intersect([4:7], Target) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        Me.DropDowns.Delete
        With Worksheets("Listing")
            lst = "'" & .Name & "'!" & _
              .Range(.Range("a1"), _
              .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Address()
         End With
        With Me.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Target.Left, _
                                  Top:=Target.Top, Width:=60, Height:=15)
             .Name = "CB"
            .OnAction = "CB_Change"
            .ControlFormat.ListFillRange = lst

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that the Comboboxes created only allow user to select and not to write into

Comment: You don't define `lst`?

Comment: I did, i just did not make it appear here

Comment: 1. The question should include *everything* relevant to the problem. The definition of `lst` would certainly be relevant. 2. To answer someone in comments precede their name with @, otherwise there will be no notification that you're responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveX controls are easier to configure than Form Controls. `MSForm.ComboBox` controls have a `Style` property that, when set to `fmStyleDropDownCombo`, makes the textbox area editable; when the style is `fmStyleDropDownList`, user input is restricted to what's in the dropdown list.

[image: ComboBox1 properties]

...with that said, [**Data Validation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56345624/1188513) is probably a better option (less bug-prone, better integrated with the worksheet/Excel, no `MSForm` dependency), if you can live with "circle invalid data" making red circles around "invalid data" that is allowed to be entered, but not in the dropdown list:

[image: DV red circle around invalid data]

Comment: I tried the activeX combobox, it works fine : ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=Target.Left, Top:=Target.Top, Width:=162, _
                Height:=16) . But the box has not the focus and i am writing in the cell behind. Is there something like Me.CB.SetFocus.

Comment: @Phoenix all MSForms controls have a `Focus` method. You need to capture the object returned by `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add` into a local variable - that'll be an `OLEObject`; then you can have a local `ctrl As MSForm.ComboBox` variable that you can set to the OLEObject's `Object` property - and from there you should have access to the `Focus` method. If not, try declaring `ctrl As MSForm.Control`.

Comment: The focus don't work, but the Ctrl.Activate do the job.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, use Data Validation instead. This will create a writable combo, based on the values in cells J3:J5

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect([4:7], Target) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        With Target.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=$J$3:$J$5"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With

        ' This will expand the list
        Target.Select
        SendKeys "%{DOWN}"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It look nice. Is there a way to expand the dropdown instantly ?

Comment: I have added some code above now. I'm not sure it is the best thing to do, though. Sending keystrokes is risky. Test it before spreading it.

Comment: @Phoenix you'll want to `.Select` the `Shape` you just added, immediately before `SendKeys`.

Comment: I have added what @MathieuGuindon suggested.

Comment: The sendkeys works great, but Data Validation can't be use to write and look for propositions at the same time apparently. I will try with ActiveX Combox.

Comment: I could also make a function to close the dropdown on a char hit, add the char to the cell, filter the list and reopen the dropdown. Is that better than using the activeX combobox ?